# Contentful getting contenttypes different

Tags: javascript, contentful, contentful-management

I am using management api, when I run following code:

```
sourceSpace.cf_space.getContentTypes().then(function(contentTypes){});
```

It returns response like that:

[image]

But when I run following code:

```
sourceSpace.cf_space.getContentType(contentTypeId).then(function(contentType){});
```

It returns response like that:

[image]

Why is that change of response in both calls. I have them to be same in both cases.

**localized** and **disabled** two fields are missing when I call .getContentType api.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: @trodrigues: help buddy.

Comment: @trodrigues help buddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until recently, those properties would not show up unless they had been set explicitly (so if you had never set "localized", it would never show up).

With some recent changes to our backend, all of those properties will always show up for newer content types, but older content types will probably still have the same behavior.

The best thing you can do for now is just set/unset them manually on the UI, or not depend on the fact that they will always be defined.